# Powerpivot 2013 + Data Model Table Names

Tags: ms-office, powerpivot, office-2013

Am just playing around with PowerPivot in Office 2013.

When i create model in PowerPivot it looks as below  (with three tables)

[image]

and when i try to analyze the data in PivotTable it comes up as

[image]

it says Table1, Table2 instead Reseller Details, Calendar.

This works fine in office 2010 powerpivot it picks right table names.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why they changed it but I can't imagine it was on purpose.

If you are dead set on showing the model table name in the field list (and why wouldn't you be) then you need to change the name of the excel table itself as well which you can do in the 'Design' tab which appears when you are in the table itself.

[image: Name table]

Not ideal but at least there is a work around.
Jacob